# select2 - Get the value of the clicked box

Tags: jquery-select2

In my Select2 multi-select boxes I want to be able to click on the selected boxes and getting their corresponding option value (or object).
This is (in a nutshell) what I have so far:

```
$('#mySelect2').next('span').find('ul').on('click', '.select2-selection__choice', function (e) {
    console.log($('#mySelect2').select2('data'));
    alert($(this).data('select2-id'));
});
```

I searched the select2 data objects but there is nothing related to the clicked box and the select2-id data attribute
seems to be random.
Where can I find some matching id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround solution.
It seems that select2 uses the title attribute in the rending list.
So the trick is to use this attribute as an id in each option.

```
<select multiple id="states" name="states[]" class="select2">
   <option title="states-AL" value="AL">Alabama</option>
   <option title="states-CA" value="CA">California</option>
   <option title="states-MI" value="MI">Michigan</option>
   <option title="states-UT" value="UT">Utah</option>
   <option title="states-WY" value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

$('#states').next('span').find('ul').on('click', '.select2-selection__choice', function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try the below code, use select2 - select and unselect event.

```
    $("#mySelect2").on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (e) {

            //get all items by, for multiple an array like ["9", "20"] will be returned
            var items= $(this).val();       

            //Last selected value
            var lastItem = e.params.data.id;

    })
```